# jquery animate and step function usage

Tags: jquery

i tried to fadeout my div with the help jquery animate and step function but my logic is not working. i want to fadeout div when animate function decrease my div height & width is 50%. i mean when div's height & width becomes almost half then i want to fadeout div very smoothly.

my code is working but the effect i want not being possible. so please have a look at my code and rectify it if possible. here is the url where u can see the implementation.
http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/12/

just need to modify this below portion

```
 grower.animate({width:0, height:0, left:(windowWidth/2 - $('#grower').width()),  top:(windowHeight/2 - $('#grower').height())},
 {
duration: 1000,
step: function(now, fx) {
                alert(now);
    if (fx.prop == "height") {
        var threshold = fx.start / 2;

        if (now < 150) {
            $(fx.elem).css("opacity", now / threshold);
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: I dont actually understand what you want to do to the code? What would be different to the way that it already is?

Comment: just goto the url and see the effect. u can see that div is getting fadeout when it's height become very small. but i want that div should be fadeout when it's height become 150 px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a different approach : instead of using the `step` function and recalculate the `opacity`, you could use the [specialEasing](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#per-property-easing) property when animating. This allows you to have a different easing for each property that is animated.
All you have to do now is define an easing function that doesn't animate until the animation reaches 50% of it's progress.
This can be done quite easy ([here's the resource](http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_create_custom_jQuery_easing_functions-OKb) that helped me to understand the easing function) :

```
$.easing['my_easing_name'] = function(p){
    return p < 0.5
               ? 0
               : 2 * (p-0.5);
};
```

Then you can use it like :

```
$('element').animate({
        prop1 : value1,
        prop2 : value2
    },{
        duration : 1000,
        specialEasing : {
            prop1 : 'liniar',
            prop2 : 'my_easing_name'
       }
});
```

Here's a demo of my version : http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/Sj4eG/32/

Comment: u point out good think but i go to ur url http://jsfiddle.net/gion_13/Sj4eG/32/ but still saw that div is not getting fadeout when it's height& width reduce 50%. so please modify ur code just to show me how to do it with easing function. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/17/)?

Sorry its not centered!

Comment: i hope u did not understand my requirement.